# Properties in JMeter for GUI and CMD

Tags: jmeter

I have a JMeter script, where I have some user defined Variables like `FILE_SAVE_PATH`. This script should be started on a command line with parameter `-J`. So in the GUI, I changed the value for the variable `FILE_SAVE_PATH` to `${__P(FILE_SAVE_PATH, "C:\svn\trunk\dir")}`, because the test should save there a file, but only on my machine. On the machine, where the script will be started from command line, it should save the file into another path.

My problem is now this: When I test this JMeter script on my machine in the GUI, I get an output of this:

```
About to replace in property of type: class org.apache.jmeter.testelement.property.StringProperty: ${__P(FILE_SAVE_PATH, "C:\svn\trunk\dir")} 
2017/04/04 17:09:38 DEBUG - jmeter.testelement.property.AbstractProperty: Not running version, return raw function string 
2017/04/04 17:09:38 DEBUG - jmeter.engine.util.ValueReplacer: Replacement result: ${__P(FILE_SAVE_PATH, "C:\svn\trunk\dir")}
```

But I think, the last line should be something like this:

```
2017/04/04 17:09:38 DEBUG - jmeter.engine.util.ValueReplacer: Replacement result: "C:\svn\trunk\dir"
```

So, how to change the test to get the result I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape every backslash with another one - `C:\\svn\\trunk\\dir`, or use unix slash, JVM's gonna handle it right: `C:/svn/trunk/dir`

And remove the doublequotes, they're not needed.

P.S. I presumed you're not using that notation in the Beanshell/JSR223 context. If you do - stop there and use the legit way to access properties.